# Getting unexpected behavior of if condition while comparing array.size() with negative value

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
template <class T>
class Queue {
  private:
    array<T, 10> elems;
    int frt = -1, bck = -1;    
};
```

When I run the following code of snippet:

```
template <class T>
void Queue<T>::Enque(T const& item) {
    cout << "Size of array:" << elems.size() << "\n";
    if (bck < elems.size()) {
        if (bck == -1) frt = 0;
        ++bck;
        elems.at(bck) = item;
        cout << "Element Inserted\n";
    } else {
        cout<<"Queue is overflow\n";
    }
}
```

I get this output:

```
Size of array:10
Queue is overflow
```

Here it is showing that the `size` is 10 and the value of `bck` is -1 but it is going to the else statement.

But if I replace the `if condition` with `if (bck < 10)` the code is working fine:

```
Size of array:10
Element Inserted
```

Can anyone help me in identifying this behavior?

Comment: What is the type of elems?

Comment: Looks like signed unsigned comparison error

Comment: Compile with all warnings turned on and fix the warnings.

Comment: Before you start learning programming, please kindly learn how to copy-paste text from a command line window to a browser and back. Do not ever make *screenshots of text*.

Comment: @KerrekSB I will keep it in mind and bring it in practice

Comment: @KerrekSB it is being done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that `elems.size()` returns some kind of unsigned integer type (akin to size_t) and thus you are mixing signed and unsigned integer types in your comparison, which is undefined behaviour iIrc - in this case, your compiler is promoting the -1 to unsigned, which if converted as-is would give 0xFFFFFFFF (2^32-1). When you write the 10 literally, both values are signed and the comparison is as you expect.

Comment: If `elems` is an `std::array`, then `size` *definitely* returns `std::size_t` which is indeed unsigned.

Comment: how can i avoid such behaviour ? should i cast the elems.size() ?

Comment: @ShvetChakra: you can change the logic of your class so that `frt` and `bck` are `size_t` and start from 0